# SAS Prompt Manager - password masking not accepted by databases (i.e. mainframe, db2, oracle, sqlsvr)

Tags: sas, password-protection, enterprise-guide

Tool: SAS EG5.1
Environment:  SAS GRID (linux)

Task: I'm trying to create a prompt via prompt manager which will deliver a masked password to the libname statement used to access tables on DB2/ORACLE/SQLSVR; I'm also trying to pass the same information to a mainframe connection script. None of the systems will accept this information, they only accept unmasked passwords.  Is there a way to pass this information in a masked fashion?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a prompt in EG make sure you select the "SAS Proprietary encryption" under "Method for encoding masked texts" (and that you selected the "Masked single line" text prompt type).

If you are using code:

```
Proc Pwencode in="PASSWORD";
run;
```

will mask the word PASSWORD in such a way that the scripts provided by SAS for remote connecting to a mainframe will work.

Post more of your code, including what you are using to connect to databases and remote connect script info if more info is needed...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether this is relevant if you're using EG as I don't use that myself, but the method I'm most familiar with is to use %window and %display statements to construct a prompt that people can use to enter a masked password. The inputs from the fields in such a prompt can be made available as macro variables.